# Chrome extension: if(string) returns false if string is empty

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a string from my **content script** to my **background page**. So I got:

Content Script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({sendBack:true,data:word});
```

Background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    if (message.sendBack) { 
        //process word (message.data)
    }
});
```

The problem begins when I try to pass an empty string to the background page. The background page can process the empty string and even alert it, but if I type:

```
if(message.data)
```

at the background page, the condition returns `false`. Why?

Comment: That's not really an extension thing.  It's a javascript thing that `""` becomes false.  Could you try `typeof message.data === "string"`?

Comment: Out of curiosity is this the syntax you are using in your Content Script? `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({sendBack:true,data:word});` It may think `word` is a variable if you are sending a string. If the variable is never instantiated, or null, js will return false. Try putting some quotes around word or making sure the variable is instantiated and populated.